# Apache Camel Ant Include pattern is not working as expected

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I need to write a route which scans for files starts with *batch* and moves to 
destination directory.

```
from(file:source?delay=2000&antInclude=batch*&readLock=changed).to(file:destination);
```

After starting route, I have created a files in source directory with following names *batchFile28845810.txt, batchFile.signed, batchFile.enc* and found file is not moved to destination directory

Comment: And if you remove `antInclude` then Camel will pickup these files? Are those files in sub folders, if so then you should use `**/batch*`

Comment: yes after removing antInclude..camel is picking up the files. they are not in sub folders ..they are in samefolder as source directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the filenames of the `source` directory on a command line? Are there perhaps any invisible characters at the beginning?

You can also try to use this `antInclude` pattern to ignore any strange stuff at the beginning of the filename.

```
*batch*
```